# Froala / PHP - image upload failure (something went wrong...)

Tags: javascript, php, wysiwyg, froala

Trying to get Froala to upload images to server in PHP environment.  Have followed exactly Froala's example [here](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/server/php/image-upload).

However, when I choose an image file, and submit, the feedback I get is an error message: "Something went wrong.  Please try again".

I have used the exact file/directory names as in the example, but obviously I am missing something.  The directory is "uploads" for image depository.

I have read most of the other Stackoverflow comments and solutions, have tried several of them, read Froala's info, but still have no success.

The code below which I am using is pretty well identical to their example.

THE EDITOR FILE: "index.php"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Include external CSS. -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.25.0/codemirror.min.css">

  <!-- Include Editor style. -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.5.1/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.5.1/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Include external JS libs. -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.25.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.25.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include Editor JS files. -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.5.1//js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <div class="sample">
    <h2>File upload example.</h2>
    <form>
      <textarea id="edit" name="content"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Initialize the editor. -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#edit').froalaEditor({
        // Set the file upload URL.
        imageUploadURL: '/upload_image.php',

        imageUploadParams: {
          id: 'my_editor'
        }
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

THE PHP FILE: "upload_image.php"

```
<?php

try {
  // File Route.
  $fileRoute = "/uploads/";

  $fieldname = "file";

  // Get filename.
  $filename = explode(".", $_FILES[$fieldname]["name"]);

  // Validate uploaded files.
  // Do not use $_FILES["file"]["type"] as it can be easily forged.
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

  // Get temp file name.
  $tmpName = $_FILES[$fieldname]["tmp_name"];

  // Get mime type.
  $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $tmpName);

  // Get extension. You must include fileinfo PHP extension.
  $extension = end($filename);

  // Allowed extensions.
  $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "svg", "blob");

  // Allowed mime types.
  $allowedMimeTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/x-png", "image/png", "image/svg+xml");

  // Validate image.
  if (!in_array(strtolower($mimeType), $allowedMimeTypes) || !in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)) {
    throw new \Exception("File does not meet the validation.");
  }

  // Generate new random name.
  $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;
  $fullNamePath = dirname(__FILE__) . $fileRoute . $name;

  // Check server protocol and load resources accordingly.
  if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "off") {
    $protocol = "https://";
  } else {
    $protocol = "http://";
  }

  // Save file in the uploads folder.
  move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $fullNamePath);

  // Generate response.
  $response = new \StdClass;
  $response->link = $protocol.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).$fileRoute . $name;

  // Send response.
  echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));

} catch (Exception $e) {
   // Send error response.
   echo $e->getMessage();
   http_response_code(404);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by doing the following:

1. on index.php file, removed the slash "/" that references 'upload_image.php'.
   Changed `imageUploadURL: '/upload_image.php',` to `imageUploadURL: 'upload_image.php',`  Hard to believe the Froala website example has this error in it, and has not been corrected...?
2. A second problem was the 'finfo' functions were not working.  I enabled it in php.ini by removing the semicolon and it now all works OK!

EDIT:  Froala commented that the "/" will work if the files are in the root directory.  Mine were not.

Answer (score 0):

From their website.

> The uploads directory must be set to a valid location before any uploads are made. The path can be any folder that is accessible and **write available.**

Please check your folder permissions, this is a common oversight.

Regards

edwoli

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but still no luck - the folder has write permission, and the uploads directory matches the code reference:  $fileRoute = "/uploads/";   I don't think it needs to be the full path name?  Hmmm...